# Initialising ElementRef in Jasmine test leads to Illegal constructor error

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am trying to initialise the scroll property in one of my Jasmine test and get error Illegal constructor. Whats wrong in the way I am initialising the scroll component.
 I have initialised it this way

component.scroll = new ElementRef({ HTMLDivElement:  new HTMLDivElement()} );

Test

```
fit('should call checkIfLastAgreement and notify that its not the last agreement when  accept is called', () => {
    component.agreementLength = 2;
    component.lastAgreement = false;
    component.activeBtn = 0;
    component.currentIndex = 0;
    component.scroll = new ElementRef({ HTMLDivElement:  new HTMLDivElement()} );
    component.myData = [{userAgreementId: 1}, { acceptanceWindowExpiry: acceptanceDateUtc }, {timeLeft: '2d'}];
                                                                                                           , {timeLeft: '2d'}];
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component.accept();

    expect(component.agreementsService.updateAgreement).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.lastAgreement).toBe(false);
    expect(component.endOfAgreements).toBe(false);
  });
```

Component

```
 @ViewChild('scroll', { read: ElementRef, static: false })
  public scroll: ElementRef<any>;
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed.  I had to remove fixture.detectChanges();